# In Lego Batman, where is Zod?

Tags: dc, lego-cinematic-universe, the-lego-batman-movie

In *The Lego Batman Movie*, we see Superman sending Zod to the Phantom Zone. Later Batman sends Joker to the Phantom Zone. However, when Joker arrives there, Zod is not among the people who are in the Phantom Zone.

Why is this? Where has he disappeared to? Has he already escaped?

Comment: I doubt the Phantom Zone scene shows all villians. After breaking out he was probably fighting with Superman (especially since it was Superman who had only recently put him in the Phantom Zone).

Comment: Might be a setup for the next Lego movie

Comment: Similar question from [sister site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68903/where-was-zod-in-the-phantom-zone) but there is still no answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Zod was in the Phantom Zone.** You see him later in the film as part of Joker's Army of Evil™.

[image: screenshot showing the Joker's Army of Evil]

Note that there are multiple villains who turn up in the later scenes *who don't appear in the earlier scene inside the Phantom Zone*. Clearly they were only intended to be a cross-section of the inmates rather than the entire population.

Comment: Wow such a good set of eyes. I just imagined that he would be the first one their as he was only just sent. Thanks.

Comment: I spotted him on a rewatch